# Master node resource usage in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a master node in Hadoop cluster. It can or cannot be also worker node.
How can I get info about the CPU/Memory usage of master node for coordinating other nodes and the one for its own worker node usage? For example, 40% of memory or CPU is used for its master node tasks (coordination of other worker nodes), 30% memory used for worker node tasks (the worker node inside the master node machine).
Is there a way to know this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a perfect way to handle the scenario by using the **JMX monitoring** of the `Namenode` and `Datanode` JVM tasks.

You will be able to track the various performance metrics of the namenode, datanode, jobtracker JVM processes.

Please refer,

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/hadoop-metrics/
https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/enabling-jmx-monitoring-for-hadoop-and-hive/